# Websphere Portal Pagebuilder Theme Migration from 6.1.5 to 7.0.0.2

Tags: websphere-portal

I am new to WebSphere portal themes.Can we migrate the WebSphere portal 6.1.5 Page builder themes&skins   to 7.0.0.2 Page builder themes&skins ? If yes,can u please provide the themes migration steps to follow.

Thanks,
Haritha.S

Answer (score 1):

If you have not customized the theme in any way, if it's just a clean out of the box Page Builder theme, the upgrade should not effect it.
If the theme has customizations, then any hard-coded references (paths to artifacts or the context root) will have to be updated.
During the migration process, any custom theme you have present in wps.ear will be moved to MigratedThemes.ear. You'll have to expand that ear file, modify your theme, then pack it back up and deploy through WAS console.
Here are detailed instructions (though they relate to WAS 7): http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Portal_V6.1.x_on_application_server_V7_Updating_custom_themes_and_skins_with_hardcoded_context_root_references_wp8